# Convert Json to separate columns in HIVE

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have 4 columns in Hive database table. First two columns are of type string, 3rd and 4th are of JSON. Type. How to extract json data in different columns. 
SERDE available in Hive seems to be handling only json data. I have both normal (STRING) and JSON data. How can I extract data in separate colums here.

Example:

```
abc 2341    {max:2500e0,value:"20",Type:"1",ProviderType:"ABC"} {Name:"ABC",minA:1200e0,StartDate:1483900200000,EndDate:1483986600000,Flags:["flag4","flag3","flag2","flag1"]}

xyz 6789    {max:1300e0,value:"10",Type:"0",ProviderType:"foo"} {Name:"foo",minA:3.14159e0,StartDate:1225864800000,EndDate:1225864800000,Flags:["foo","foo"]}
```

Comment: These are not valid JSON documents. The keys should be qualified, e.g. `"value":"20"` and not `value:"20"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Let me see if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a fixed JSON

```
create table mytable (str string,i int,jsn1 string, jsn2 string);

insert into mytable values
    ('abc',2341,'{"max":2500e0,"value":"20","Type":"1","ProviderType":"ABC"}','{"Name":"ABC","minA":1200e0,"StartDate":1483900200000,"EndDate":1483986600000,"Flags":["flag4","flag3","flag2","flag1"]}')
   ,('xyz',6789,'{"max":1300e0,"value":"10","Type":"0","ProviderType":"foo"}','{"Name":"foo","minA":3.14159e0,"StartDate":1225864800000,"EndDate":1225864800000,"Flags":["foo","foo"]}')
;
```

---

```
select  str,i
       ,jsn1_max,jsn1_value,jsn1_type,jsn1_ProviderType
       ,jsn2_Name,jsn2_minA,jsn2_StartDate,jsn2_EndDate
       ,jsn2_Flags

from    mytable

        lateral view json_tuple (jsn1,'max','value','Type','ProviderType') 
            j1 as jsn1_max,jsn1_value,jsn1_type,jsn1_ProviderType

        lateral view json_tuple (jsn2,'Name','minA','StartDate','EndDate','Flags') 
            j2 as jsn2_Name,jsn2_minA,jsn2_StartDate,jsn2_EndDate,jsn2_Flags
;
```

---

```
+-----+------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| str |  i   | jsn1_max | jsn1_value | jsn1_type | jsn1_providertype | jsn2_name | jsn2_mina | jsn2_startdate | jsn2_enddate  |            jsn2_flags             |
+-----+------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| abc | 2341 | 2500.0   |         20 |         1 | ABC               | ABC       | 1200.0    |  1483900200000 | 1483986600000 | ["flag4","flag3","flag2","flag1"] |
| xyz | 6789 | 1300.0   |         10 |         0 | foo               | foo       | 3.14159   |  1225864800000 | 1225864800000 | ["foo","foo"]                     |
+-----+------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hey, Actually the given input would be in as given in example.  need to convert input to proper json format to apply this logic.

Comment: Since I also answered your other post, I  think we are covered :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806431/string-transformation-in-hive/42806701#42806701

Comment: yes, instead of jsn1 and jsn2, I will have regexp_replace code.. right? I am testing this change.