# string Transformation in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have a string as given below in one of the columns in hive table.

```
{ABC:"ABCVAL",XYZ:"XYZVAL"}
```

I want to convert it to in HIVE

```
{"ABC":"ABCVAL","XYZ":"XYZVAL"}
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple version**

Assuming the value does not contain colon (`:`) symbol.

Look for sequence of characters other than `{,:` (key) followed by `:`

```
select regexp_replace('{ABC:"ABCVAL",XYZ:"XYZVAL"}','(?<key>[^{,:]+):','"${key}":');

{"ABC":"ABCVAL","XYZ":"XYZVAL"}
```

**Safe version**

Look for optional `{` (beforekey), followed by a sequence of characters (key) which is immediately followed by `:` (colon), followed by `"`, sequence of characters (value) and then `"` again, followed by `,` or `]` (aftervalue)

```
select  regexp_replace
        (
            '{ABC:"ABCVAL",XYZ:"XYZVAL"}'
           ,'(?<beforekey>\\{)?(?<key>.*?)(?<colon>:)(?<value>".*?")(?<aftervalue>[,}])'
           ,'${beforekey}"${key}"${colon}${value}${aftervalue}'
        )
;

{"ABC":"ABCVAL","XYZ":"XYZVAL"}
```

Comment: Can You add little explanation about why this works ?